# Read tweets for 3 weeks through Twitter Search API

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-search

I am totally confused by the vast amount of data about the search API, with different and confusing point of views. All I need is simple answers to some questions.

I need tweets about certain keywords for my research. I will search for those keywords up to 3-4 weeks.  We opt for search API, through this way we will be able to read tweets of last few days, and repeat the process every specific days and hopefully won't miss too any.

1. How many tweets can I search in one hour, with one application?
2. I may have 60 to 70 key words to search. Is it a good idea to use one Twitter developer application for all the keywords, or create more application (eg 1 application for each keyword).
3. How many applications can I register/create on one account?
4. In my case, Is it a good idea to use search API, instead of streaming API?

I know the questions are trivial, but there are so many answers. And by your help, maybe I can get more solid overview.

Comment: To answer 1) -- Rate limits

The GET search/tweets is part of the Twitter REST API 1.1 and is rate limited similarly to other v1.1 methods. See REST API Rate Limiting in v1.1 for information on that model. At this time, users represented by access tokens can make 180 requests/queries per 15 minutes. Using application-only auth, an application can make 450 queries/requests per 15 minutes on its own behalf without a user context. --- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Comment: 1. Try it and find out? It is likely to be in the docs too. 2. One application for them all. 4. There is an explanation of the streaming API in the devs site, maybe that will help?

Answer (score 1):

I have done Tweet search application in Rails.

1 Twitter API has limits on number of tweets that you can search per window frame
    https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits  this link will give you limits.

presently limits is set to 450 requests per 15 minutes(450x200(per request) X 15 X 4)    tweets but I think you need to customize the options to fetch tweets that are not in your  database. You might get same tweets again and again. I guess **Since_id & result_type** will help you in that.

2 It depends upon the popularity of the keywords.But I don't think you can get this much tweets in one application. Its hit and trial attempt.

3 I don't exactly know the limits for this.

4 Streaming API would be best but If you don't need much of the tweets than search api seems fine.